# Visual studio 2010 setup project problem

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I've made an application that uses .NET framework 3.5 SP1 and SQL Server 2008 Express.
Application is fine and now i'm going to to make a setup project for this.

When I first build my setup it was fine as all the prerequisites were not included in setup.

But I want my setup to install .NET 3.5 SP1 and SQL SERVER 2008 Express also. So for this I've changed the options in setup project's properties from "Download prerequisites from following location" to "Download prerequisites from  the same location as my application". In addition to that I've also checked the options above like .NET 3.5 SP1 and SQL Server 2008 Express etc.

After doing all this I build my project again. This time I'm Getting 57 Errors.

---

- Error    1   The install location for
  prerequisites has not been set to
  'component vendor's web site' and the
  file
  'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet.msp'
  in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can
  not be located on disk. See Help for
  more information.    D:\MindStrike
  Setup\MindStrike
  Setup.vdproj MindStrike Setup
- Error    2   The install location for
  prerequisites has not been set to
  'component vendor's web site' and the
  file
  'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet_64.msp'
  in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can
  not be located on disk. See Help for
  more information.    D:\MindStrike
  Setup\MindStrike
  Setup.vdproj MindStrike Setup
  Error    3   The install location for
  prerequisites has not been set to
  'component vendor's web site' and the
  file
  'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\clr.msp' in
  item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not
  be located on disk. See Help for more
  information. D:\MindStrike
  Setup\MindStrike
  Setup.vdproj MindStrike Setup
- Error    4   The install location for
  prerequisites has not been set to
  'component vendor's web site' and the
  file
  'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\clr_64.msp'
  in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can
  not be located on disk. See Help for
  more information.    D:\MindStrike
  Setup\MindStrike
  Setup.vdproj MindStrike Setup

---

As the question will become too large so I'm just pasting 3 errors but there are totally 57 errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search suggests you might want to take a look at this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d3c1991a-9353-43f0-be82-2dacedc1ceba/

---

Pertinent Info from section 2.3.1.1 of the [VS2008SP1Readme.htm](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues):

> If the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper package is selected in the
>   Prerequisite dialog box for a Setup project or in ClickOnce
>   publishing, and also the "Download prerequisites from the same
>   location as my application" option is selected, the following build
>   error is shown:
>
> The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component
>   vendor's web site' and the file 'dotNetFx35setup.exe' in item
>   'Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1' cannot be located on disk.

To resolve this issue:

**Update the Package Data**

1. Open the [Program Files]\Microsoft
   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 folder or
   %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft
   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 on x64
   operating systems
2. Edit the Product.xml file in Notepad.
3. Paste the following into the < PackageFiles > element:

   - `<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg.exe"/>`
   - `<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_x64.exe"/>`
   - `<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_ia64.exe"/>`
4. Find the element for < PackageFile
   Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-x86-en-US.exe" and change the PublicKey
   value to:
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
5. Find the element for < PackageFile
   Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-amd64-en-US.exe" and change the PublicKey
   value to the same as in step 4 above
6. Save the product.xml file

**Download and Extract the Core Installation Files**

1. Navigate to the following URL:
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=118080
2. Download the dotNetFx35.exe file to your local disk.
3. Open a Command Prompt window and change to the directory to which you downloaded dotNetFx35.exe.
4. At the command prompt, type:  `dotNetFx35.exe /x:`.  This will extract the Framework files to a folder named “WCU” in the current directory.
5. Copy the contents of the WCU\dotNetFramework folder and paste them
   in the `%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1` folder
   (`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1` on x64
   operating systems). Note: Do not copy the WCU\dotNetFramework folder
   itself.

   There should be 5 folders under the WCU folder, and each of these should now appear in the DotNetFx35SP1 folder. The folder structure should resemble the following:

   - DotNetFx35SP1 (folder)

     - dotNetFX20 (folder
     - dotNetFX30 (folder)
     - dotNetFX35 (folder)
     - dotNetMSP (folder)
     - TOOLS folder)
     - en (or some other localized folder)
     - dotNetFx35setup.exe (file)

You may now delete the files and folders you downloaded and extracted in steps 2 and 4.

Comment: Windows 8 users, see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865128/how-can-i-extract-net-3-5-on-a-windows-8-pc-for-building-a-setup-package