# How can I extract .Net 3.5 on a Windows 8 PC for building a setup package?

Tags: windows-8, installation

The [instructions for including .Net 3.5 SP1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues) say to:

1. At the command prompt, type:
   dotNetFx35.exe /x:.
   This will extract the Framework files to a folder named “WCU” in the current directory.

However, running this command on a Windows 8 box doesn't do anything, so how else can I extract the files for building a setup package (for use with the Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Projects)

Comment: This isn't the right way to go about it, it is rather important that you use the bootstrapper.  The 3.5SP1 revision for Win8 is different.  There are easier ways to go about it, including doing nothing since it already automatically prompts the user to get the install going, running dism.exe so the built-in version of .NET 3.5SP1 gets installed and using a .config file to simply make your program run on .NET 4.5.  You didn't give enough details to recommend the best solution.

Comment: @HansPassant I already have 3.5SP1 installed (via dism), but  I'm trying to extract the bootstrapper, for use in a setup package.

Comment: We can also extract it with any advanced Archiver (7Zip/Winrar).

Answer (score 0):

Running in to the same scenario, I reverted to a Windows 7 virtual machine to run the extract process.